# How to prove that $\mu=\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, dirac-delta

Let  $I$ be an interval of  $\mathbb R$ and $\mu $ a Borel positive finite measure on $\mathbb R$. 
I would like to know why, if 
$$\int_{I} |t-s|^2 d\mu(t) = 0, \quad \forall s\in I,$$ then $\mu = c\,  \delta $ for some $c\in \mathbb R$, where here, $\delta$ is the Dirac measure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For $I = \emptyset$, this is the empty criterion and so does not say anything about $\mu$.

Comment: Any $\mu$ concentrated on $\mathbb{R}\setminus I$ satisfies the condition. And $\delta$ only satisfies it if $0 \notin I$ (or $I = [0,0]$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $I=[a,b]$ and for simplicity $s\in(a,b)$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be such that $(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)\subset(a,b)$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
0=\int_I|t-s|^2d\mu(t)&=&\int_{[a,\,s-\epsilon]}|t-s|^2d\mu(t)+\int_{[s-\epsilon,\,s+\epsilon]}|t-s|^2d\mu(t)+\int_{[s+\epsilon,\,b]}|t-s|^2d\mu(t)\\
&\ge&\int_{[a,\,s-\epsilon]}|t-s|^2d\mu(t)\\
&\ge&\epsilon^2\int_{[a,\,s-\epsilon]}d\mu(t)\\
&\ge&0
\end{eqnarray}
from which one obtains that $\mu([a,\,s-\epsilon])=0$. Similarly $\mu([s+\epsilon,\,b])=0$. From these, it is easy to derive 
$$\mu([a,s))=0,\mu((s,b])=0$$
Let $\mu(\{s\})=c\ge0$. Then $\mu=c\delta(s)$.